# One RO User Vs Multiple RO Users for Redshift database

Tags: amazon-redshift

We have two redshift databases for a single region in our AWS cluster. The database is accessed by many users for running RO (read-only) queries. What are the best practices for creating RO users in the database? Shall we create a single user (accessed by every one) to run queries, or create multiple users for individual logins?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple users that will have the same permissions you should create a group with the desired permissions and assign all these users to that group.  This makes maintaining and permissions easier and stops any one-off mistakes in setting up a new user.  Also, having shared credentials creates issues with tracking user activity and password changing every time someone leaves the organization.